# Complex html layout with div

Tags: javascript, css, html

I want to do some kind of naval battle game in HTML5/Javascript using drag and drop on a grid (composed of `div` elements). The starting point is a `div` with 20 * 20 identical cells.

I have to perform some complex layout like in the image below and this layout may be dynamically modified by Javascript (e.g. when a ship is moved).

I know how to perform merged row cells but I cannot find out how to merge columns (like in the example below).

Is it possible with `div`s or would you recommend a `table`?

```
 _______________________
|__|__|__|__|__|__|  |__|
|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|
|__|__|_____|__|     |__|
|__|__|__|__|__|_____|__|
|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|
```

Sorry for not posting a nicer image but my reputation is too low to post images.

Comment: what kind of ship is at F3? Can you show some code of what you've tried?

Comment: Post the code on fiddle to improve the question

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

To be simple use a table, you have the rowspan and colspan properties.  But for ease of maintenance, I recommend not using a table, and designing a div layout similar to how Bootstrap implements div based table layouts. http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables

If your design has to be responsive, you do not want to use table, td, tr elements, you will need to come up with a div based layout.

Other table layout libraries/techniques: http://www.sitepoint.com/responsive-data-tables-comprehensive-list-solutions/

Answer (score 0):

I would use a grid with div's. An place the boats on top of the grid with an image and store boat info as class properties on a per cell basis.

Answer (score 0):

combination of bootstrap with jquery should be possible, for example:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3 shipSize3"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-3"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 shipSize6"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

then you would be able to just change class with jquery(.removeClass(),.addClass()):

```
if (shipSize3 === 'killed'){
 $('div').removeClass('shipSize3');
} else {}
```

Answer (score -1):

It is possible, [here is the code](http://jsbin.com/ritilocume/edit?html,output).

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [**it would be preferable**](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes

Comment: My Goodness. This is the straight forward way to answer questions. No offence, just understanding how people think. Thanks.